# Vue.js component lifecycle for children

Tags: vue.js, components, lifecycle

What order are child components created and mounted in? I know that the lifecycle for a single component is documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), but I couldn't find anything that described when children were created and mounted.

For example, what is the creation and mounting order for the following component?

```
<template>
    <div class='parent'>
        <child-1/>
        <child-2/>
        <child-3/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 16):

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f) to be especially helpful in explaining the order of parent/child lifecycle hooks execution. This diagram in particular offers a nice summary of the process.

[image: Vue parent/child components' lifecycle hooks execution order]

Also have a look at [this post](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/order-of-lifecycle-hooks-for-parent-and-child/6681/2) by **LinusBorg** on the vuejs forum.

> - `beforeCreate()` and `created()` of the parent run first.
> - Then the parent’s template is being rendered, which means the child components get created.
> - so now the children’s `beforeCreate()` and `created()` hooks execute respectively.
> - these child components mount to DOM elements, which calls their `beforeMount()` and `mounted()` hooks.
> - and only then, after the parent’s template has finished, can the parent be mounted to the DOM, so finally the parent’s `beforeMount()` and `mounted()` hooks are called.

Answer (score 2):

In Vue 3, the lifecycle hook execution order can be found in a part of its [tests](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/1070f127a78bfe7da6fe550cc272ef11a1f434a0/packages/runtime-core/__tests__/apiOptions.spec.ts#L618-L661).

The rule of thumb is: with the exception of `created` hooks (which are now replaced by `setup()`), all hooks prefixed with before executes top-down (parent run first) while the "after" hooks execute bottom-up (children run first).

Both `beforeCreated` and `created` hooks execute top-down, however (as a child can only be created after the parent renders).

Answer (score 0):

As the first response give a good view of the creation/mounting process it fails to respond for the destruction process.

here is what happen :

1. app created

// we add the parent

1. parent Created
2. child Created
3. child Mounted
4. parent Mounted

// now we remove the parent :

1. parent ready to unmount
2. child ready to unmount
3. child unMounted
4. parent unMounted

PS : beware that beforeDestroy & destroyed in Vue 2 became beforeUnmounted & unMounted un Vue 3