# Problem when add a new control on map using OpenLayers and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, openlayers

I'm trying to add a custom control on my map using the OpenLayers with Vue.js.

I have the component Explore.vue that creates my "map" (olmap) using the OL and I pass it through binding to the child component LeftSideBar2.vue.

When I try to add a new control in my map, the Vue shows the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.olmap.addControl is not a function"
```

Does someone know what is happening?

My files are:

**Explore.vue:**

Template:

```
<explore-left-side-bar2 v-bind:olmap="olmap"/>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  name: 'Explore',
  data () {
    return {
      olmap: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    initComponent: function () {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      this.olmap = new Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          baseLayerGroup
        ],
        view: new View({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 5
        })
      })
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.initComponent()
  },
  components: {
    ExploreLeftSideBar2
  }
}
```

**LeftSidebar2.vue:**

Script:

```
export default {
  name: 'LeftSideBar2',
  props: ['olmap'],
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    initComponent: function () {
      var sidebar = new Sidebar({ element: 'ol-sb-sidebar', position: 'left' })
      this.olmap.addControl(sidebar)      
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.initComponent()
  },
  components: {
    LeftSideBarLayerTree
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have bound an Object `olmap={}`to a component which in returns calls a function `this.olmap.addControls()` that doesn't exist on the object which you pass as a prop. I think you are trying to do instead, is call addControls() on the OpenLayers.Map instance.

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434057/3125245) explains, `mounted` hooks are called for child components before their parents, meaning that `LeftSidebar2.vue` will call `this.olmap.addControl(sidebar)` when `olmap` is still the default empty object declared in the `data` method of `Explore.vue`.

There are a cuople of ways you could work around this:

You could initialise `olmap` in the `created` hook of `Explore.vue` rather than the `mounted` hook.

or

You could use a `v-if` to exclude `LeftSidebar2.vue` until after `olmap` has been initialised.