# Vue.js - Why is my parent component being mounted before the child component is mounted?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt version `2.15.7` and Vue `2.6.14`. My understanding is that child components are mounted *before* the parent component is mounted, [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434057/2608515).

However, in my project I'm experiencing the opposite:

#### Parent.vue

```vue
<template>
    <div class="parent">
        <MessageCard ref="messageCard"></MessageCard>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log("Parent Mounted");
        console.log(this.$refs.messageCard); // undefined
    }
}
</script>
```

#### MessageCard.vue

```vue
<template>
    <div class="messageCard">Hello</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log("Child mounted");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The output on my console shows:

```
Parent mounted
undefined
Child mounted
```

[image]

According to [the vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/order-of-lifecycle-hooks-for-parent-and-child/6681/2) Shouldn't the child component be mounted *before* the parent? I need to call methods on the child, but it's `undefined`. I've even tried `this.$nextTick()`, only to find the same results. I understand the resources I linked to are from 2018 and 2017 respectively... has this behavior changed in the last 4 years?

Comment: You understood it correctly. A codesandbox might help to see exactly why because that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Ok, if the expected behavior is that `child` should indeed mount before `parent`, then I'll spend some time re-creating more parts of my project from scratch until the error shows up again. I'm using nuxt, pages, and `this.$route`, so it might take some time to get to the root-cause of this.